# Can't connect to RDS with ConfigServer Security and Firewall enabled

Tags: linux, amazon-rds, configserver

When I try to connect to my RDS instance it fails with a (111) error. If I disable the firewall:

```
csf -x
```

I can connect.
If I try to add the instance via endpoint:

```
csf -a <RDS Endpoint>
```

csf errors with:

```
<RDS Instance> is not a valid IP/CIDR
```

Is there a way to make this work without having to disable csf?

Answer (score 1):

As I've been working with CSF and RDS I've discovered the CSF actually has an option for dynamically getting the IP on it's own. This is a great option since theoretically the IP could change for your RDS instance.

1. Edit /etc/csf/csf.dyndns and paste in your RDS endpoint
2. Edit /etc/csf/csf.conf

   - Change value of DYNDNS to greater than 0 ie. DYNDNS = "60"
   - Since this is your database, set DYNDNS_IGNORE = "1"
3. Restart CSF and LFD

   - `SUDO CSF -RA`
4. Wait until the DYNDNS value has elapsed and you should be good to go. If not, check your block lists

Answer (score 0):

I was able to grab the region from my RDS Instance endpoint:

```
us-east-2
```

I searched for the corresponding EC2 ranges on the Amazon IP ranges list here:

```
https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json
```

I added the ranges needed to csf:

```
csf -a 18.224.0.0/14
csf -a 18.216.0.0/14
```

I reloaded the firewall

```
csf -r
```

I was then able to connect to the database

Answer (score 0):

1. Get your RDS instance internal IP address. Assuming you are using EC2 and linux/ubuntu as well, SSH into your instance and type: 
   `host xxxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com` (substituting your RDS endpoint) - this will return your RDS internal IP address
2. Add this ip to /etc/csf/csf.allow and /etc/csf/csf.ignore